# How to get a filter option like SSMS with Visual studio's Server explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, server-explorer

I am using Linq to Sql, for which I am using Visual Studio's Server Explorer to drag and drop stored procedures.

Now the thing is my database has around 200-300 stored procedures, and searching for the stored procedure I want becomes a task in itself.

I was wondering if there is a way I could use filter like I remember using with Sql Server Management Studio.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, install the Productivity Power Tools extension. That will add a new "Solution Navigator" tabbed control, from which you can make a "global" text search in your solution.

It will show you everything that matches the partial entered text (xml files, cs files, classes, methods, etc).

That is very close to what you need.